# How can I make an SqlSessionFactory uses specific TransactionManager?

Tags: mybatis, spring-mybatis, transactionmanager, mybatis-configuration

For a set of multiple database, I successfully configured JDBC/JPA configurations.

```java
@Db1 @Bean Datasource dataSourceDb1();
@Db1 @Bean AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryDb1(@Db1 DataSource);
@Db1 @Bean TransactionManager transactionManagerDb1(@Db1 DataSource);

@Db2 @Bean Datasource dataSourceDb2();
@Db2 @Bean AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryDb2(@Db2 DataSource);
@Db2 @Bean TransactionManager transactionManagerDb2(@Db2 DataSource);
```

As you can see all configurations are separated for each database.

Now I want to configure MyBatis for each databases.

I know I can produce an `SqlSessionFactory` like this.

```java
    @Db1
    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("application.db1.mybatis.configuration")
    org.apache.ibatis.session.Configuration mybatisConfigurationDb1() {
        return new org.apache.ibatis.session.Configuration();
    }

    @Db1
    @Bean
    public SqlSessionFactory sqlSessionFactoryDb1(
            @Db1 final DataSource dataSource,
            @Db1 final org.apache.ibatis.session.Configuration configuration) throws Exception {
        final SqlSessionFactoryBean factoryBean = new SqlSessionFactoryBean();
        factoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
        factoryBean.setConfiguration(configuration);
        factoryBean.setVfs(SpringBootVFS.class); // // TODO: Check, works as expected? Required, actually?
        return factoryBean.getObject();
    }
```

My question is, How can I make above MyBatis configuration for `@Db1` use the `@Db1 transactionManagerDb1`?

And, in a same way, make another MyBatis configuration for `@Db2` use the `@Db2 transactionManagerDb2`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A SqlSessionFactory will use the transaction manager associated with the Datasource. MyBatis is using Spring's native transaction management so you can configure Datasources and transaction managers as is normal in Spring. The trick is to create multiple SqlSessionFactories and associate mappers to them.

The basic idea is to make two SqlSessionFactories and give them different names:

```java
// configure Datasources and transaction managers as normal, then...

@Bean(name = "SessionFactory1")
public SqlSessionFactory sqlSessionFactory1(Datasource...) {
  ...
}

@Bean(name = "SessionFactory2")
public SqlSessionFactory sqlSessionFactory2(Datasource...) {
  ...
}
```

Then use the MapperScan annotation to attach different mappers to each factory:

```java
@MapperScan(basePackages = "foo.bar.mapper1", sqlSessionFactoryRef = "SessionFactory1")
@MapperScan(basePackages = "foo.bar.mapper2", sqlSessionFactoryRef = "SessionFactory2")
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I was asking which transaction manager will each `SeqlSessionFactory` uses and how can I configure to do so.

Comment: The SqlSessionFactory will use the transaction manager associated with the datasource. With the MyBatis-Spring integration, MyBatis is using Spring's native transaction management - we didn't implement a different transaction manager just for MyBatis in Spring. So what I've shown is all you have to do. You associate different datasources with different transaction managers, then different SqlSessionFactories with different datasources. It all works together.

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate clarification. That's the one that I wanted to know. Can you please put your comment to the answer?

Comment: I've added the clarification